# Pop-up over overflow:hidden container

Tags: html, css, popup

I have table with overflow-y: hidden and -x:scroll options.
Also I have pop-up inside td, but they are hidden because table properties.
Is there some methods showing pop-ups in this case?

I can't change overflow properties of the table, so I can work only with td and pop-up container.

Thank you.

```
<div class="table-wrap">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="info-popup">
          <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
          <div class="info-hidden">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum minima nostrum velit repellat id, alias voluptatum animi, iste, voluptas sunt inventore quia obcaecati magni et.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> 
        text 1
      </td>
       <td>
        <div class="info-popup">
          <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
          <div class="info-hidden">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum minima nostrum velit repellat id, alias voluptatum animi, iste, voluptas sunt inventore quia obcaecati magni et.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> 
        text 1
      </td>
      <td>text 3</td>
      <td>text 4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>text 1</td>
      <td>text 2</td>
      <td>text 3</td>
      <td>text 4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="info-popup">
          <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
          <div class="info-hidden">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum minima nostrum velit repellat id, alias voluptatum animi, iste, voluptas sunt inventore quia obcaecati magni et.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> 
        text 1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="info-popup">
          <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
          <div class="info-hidden">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum minima nostrum velit repellat id, alias voluptatum animi, iste, voluptas sunt inventore quia obcaecati magni et.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> 
        text 1
      </td>
      <td>text 3</td>
      <td>text 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.table-wrap {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   height: auto;
   min-height: 0.1%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #AEB6BF;
}

td {
  padding: 15px;
  position: static;
}

thead tr  th {
  background: #212F3C;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
   padding: 10px 15px;
}

.info-popup {
    position: relative;
}

.info-popup i {
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info-hidden {
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(170, 184, 206, 0.4);
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    top: 10px;
    white-space: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 300ms;
}

.info-popup:hover .info-hidden {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaintz/2kq6L73a/107/

Comment: Check your css starting

Comment: popup showing on hover. what is the problem? I have added the script to show icon:   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

Comment: There is an approach for this, but you’d have to check if that will work in your specific situation here: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/